# How to get the Lowest Quality YouTube video?

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have a code snippet that converts a YouTube video to an .mp4 and stores it in my server. It's doing everything correctly, but it get's a High Quality version of the video, and my server essentially times out. Is there a way I could perform a check to see if the video is not above 20 MBs and get the lowest quality of the video?

Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$format = 'video/mp4';
parse_str(file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . $id), $info);
$streams = $info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];

$streams = explode(',', $streams);

foreach($streams as $stream) {
    parse_str($stream, $data);
    if(stripos($data['type'], $format) !== false) {
        $video = fopen($data['url'] . '&signature=' . $data['sig'], 'r');
        $file = fopen($_GET['id'] . '.mp4', 'w');
        stream_copy_to_stream($video, $file);
        fclose($video);
        fclose($file);
        echo '<a href="./' . $_GET['id'] . '.mp4">Download</a>';
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code you can get the Content-Length (size) of a resource:

```
$url = "http://some-adress/test.php";
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$content_length = $headers["Content-Length"];
```

If you parse the stream map you have to look for the "itag" which is the quality of the video.
This is an example of a preg_match that gets the itags:

```
preg_match('/itag=([0-9]+)/',$url,$tm);
```

And this is a list for all the codes with their meaning:

```
    $typeMap = array();
    $typeMap[13] = array("13", "3GP", "Low Quality - 176x144");
    $typeMap[17] = array("17", "3GP", "Medium Quality - 176x144");
    $typeMap[36] = array("36", "3GP", "High Quality - 320x240");
    $typeMap[5]  = array("5", "FLV", "Low Quality - 400x226");
    $typeMap[6]  = array("6", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360");
    $typeMap[34] = array("34", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360");
    $typeMap[35] = array("35", "FLV", "High Quality - 854x480");
    $typeMap[120] = array("120", "FLV", "High Quality - 1280x720");
    $typeMap[43] = array("43", "WEBM", "Low Quality - 640x360");
    $typeMap[44] = array("44", "WEBM", "Medium Quality - 854x480");
    $typeMap[45] = array("45", "WEBM", "High Quality - 1280x720");
    $typeMap[18] = array("18", "MP4", "Medium Quality - 480x360");
    $typeMap[22] = array("22", "MP4", "High Quality - 1280x720");
    $typeMap[37] = array("37", "MP4", "High Quality - 1920x1080");
    $typeMap[38] = array("38", "MP4", "High Quality - 4096x230");
```

Source: http://www.ngcoders.com/php-script/php-youtube-video-downloader-script/